# Unclosed regular expression using ReactJs on codepen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

So I have this pen https://codepen.io/DiMatias/pen/dzzpBx on codepen. I've been around this for the last hour and I just can't find the solution. Already added the JSX Transformer but with no success. May somebody help me please?

```
  render(){
    return (
       <div className="row">
          <div className="col">
              <img src = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/04/10/17/05/stripes-26447_960_720.png" alt="Representing present" />
           </div>
       </div>
    );
 }
```

It gives me error in this piece of code. On the first closing tag of div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that component that's causing the error - it's your `List` component that has the error.

Your code says:

```
render() {
  return () {
```

when it should be

```
render() {
   return (
     ...
   )
}
```

Your other components are written correctly.